# How to detect which custom keyboard (ios 8) is currently in use for text entering

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, ios-app-extension, custom-keyboard

I am using this solution (https://stackoverflow.com/a/25786928) to detect all custom keyboards activated in Settins app (iOS 8):

```
- (void)printoutAllActiveKeyboards {
   // Array of all active keyboards
   NSArray *keyboards = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation] objectForKey:@"AppleKeyboards"]; 
   for (NSString *keyboard in keyboards)
      NSLog(@"Custom keyboard: %@", keyboard);
}
```

But this in not enough for my project - I need to know which custom keyboard is currently chosen by the user for text entering. I have research stackoverflow and other resources but not found any solution for this. Is there any way to detect in my app which custom keyboard in currently chosen for text entering?

Thank you!

Comment: Not sure if this is question is still relevant for you today, but for anybody else who comes over this question, there is a solution that still works in 2018 here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26368224/7349426

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at this `UIApplication` API method to disable custom keyboards:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application shouldAllowExtensionPointIdentifier:(NSString *)extensionPointIdentifier {
    if ([extensionPointIdentifier isEqualToString: UIApplicationKeyboardExtensionPointIdentifier]) {
         return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Maybe you can modify the value of `UIApplicationKeyboardExtensionPointIdentifier` to match your needs

Comment: The question is about how to know which custom keyboard is currently chosen. Not disable custom keyboard. This API only help to disable custom keyboard only.

Comment: This code part helps with my problem.