# iOS detect keyboard layout (e.g. QWERTY, AZERTY)

Tags: ios, keyboard, internationalization, uitextfield, autosuggest

I am building a custom suggestion/autocorrection feature in an iOS app. It must detect accidental adjacent keypresses and compare this to a known word list to suggest the word it thinks the user intended to type.

For example, if the custom word list contains `cat`, `dog`, `monkey`, and the user types `cst`, the app can determine that the most likely word was `cat` (because `s` is adjacent to the `a` key)

[image: QWERTY keyboard showing cst]

This will work on a standard [QWERTY keyboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QWERTY), but what happens if the user is using an AZERTY keyboard?

[image]

For the autocorrect/suggest to work reliably, the app must be able to detect the keyboard layout in use.

In iOS, it is possible to obtain a [`UITextInputMode`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextinputmode) object from a `UITextField`. This object has a `primaryLanguage` (string) property, which will display the locale (e.g. `en-GB`), but this does not contain enough granularity to distinguish between `English (Australia) QWERTY` and `English (Australia) AZERTY`. In both cases, the `primaryLanguage` is `en-AU`.

Is it possible to detect the keyboard layout in iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not been able to find a clean solution to this problem.
Maybe this would be worth a TSI ticket to discuss it with Apple employees.

I know that this will not be a satisfying answer, but I would still like to share my thoughts here for future readers:

1. [Private API of UITextInputMode](https://github.com/LeoNatan/Apple-Runtime-Headers/blob/55e72453504af7d763f87f09814ff25798f899d1/tvOS/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKeyboardInputMode.h):

   `textField.textInputMode?.value(forKey: "identifierWithLayouts")`

   This will return a string like `de_DE@sw=QWERTZ-German;hw=Automatic` from which you can infer the keyboard layout.
2. UserDefaults

   `UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "AppleKeyboards")`

   This will return a list of all keyboards that the user has installed. In most cases, this will only be one language (besides the emoji keyboard).
   For example:

   `Optional(<__NSCFArray 0x600003b8e6c0>(en_US@sw=QWERTY;hw=Automatic,emoji@sw=Emoji))`

   You could also iterate over `UserDefaults.standard.dictionaryRepresentation()` and search for QWERTZ/QWERTY/AZERTY within the values.
3. With much manual effort, you could maybe encode `UITextInputModes` to binary data in all ambiguous cases like en_AU. Something like
   `NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject:textField.textInputMode, requiringSecureCoding: false)` can then be used to compare binary encodings of the user's `textInputMode` at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I have found [this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26153336/how-do-i-find-out-the-current-keyboard-used-on-ios8) that may have a solution for you. No sure it's still working, but it shows in the question how to get the current instaled keyboards, and someone provided a "gray area" solution, as it seems that there is no direct way to achieve what you intend to do.
Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

AppleLanguages object at index 0 is common way to get input language. Instead of trying to determinate which language users are  using and default layout, as far I worked with custom keyboard extension, I used one of recommended ways from Apple: use separate keyboard layout for each language. In other way I don't think you will have a stable and productive prediction, auto correct, by the way. As for auto correct I used SymSpell (https://github.com/AmitBhavsarIphone/SymSpell) and different dictionaries from https://github.com/wolfgarbe/SymSpell/tree/master/SymSpell.FrequencyDictionary to make my own RealmDb for each language. So far it was a little work to do, but finally my keyboard extension was publisehd in App Store. [Note: I am not related with SynSpell owners or coders] See images [image]

[image]

[image]