# SwiftUI Get current keyboard layout - QWERTY/QWERTZ/Nordic etc

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit

Okay, so I need to detect what keyboard layout is used in my TextField, whether its QWERTY, QWERTZ Nordic or AZERTY I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61249593/ios-detect-keyboard-layout-e-g-qwerty-azerty) and thought about using textField.textInputMode but I'm not sure how I'm supposed to do that.

Comment: just try to print this in init() ```UITextField().textInputMode?.value(forKey: "identifierWithLayouts")```

Comment: I'm using swiftui tho, where do I write this line? in onAppear of my textfield?

Comment: you can either write in onAppear or init of your struct.

Comment: Yeah that just returns nil